# Is it possible to import a Witcher 1 savegame to the XBox 360 Witcher 2?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, the-witcher-2, the-witcher

So, my poor laptop can't play Witcher 2, not a snowball's chance in hell.  Is there *any* way to somehow import a Witcher savegame into the Witcher 2 on the 360?  Even if it means downloading a savegame for the PC version and somehow converting it to 360, or something else entirely.  I mostly want it for the equipment, though I don't know if the files for the imported equipment are even in the xbox version of the game...

Rather disappointing that the only curved silver sword in the game has to be imported... effectively barring 360 players from ever having it...

Comment: Personally, if it were me and I wanted importable items from the PC version AND I were crazy enough, I'd start by asking if there is a way to convert a PC save to an Xbox 360 Save. I'd also start by attempting this with vanilla.

Comment: I did mention that in the above question as well as in the bounty.  The thing is, there are methods to convert certain PC savegames to a 360 save, but the methods vary by game from what I know.  I can do it with Dragon Age Origins for example.  I don't know if such a method exists for Witcher or not.

Answer (score 3):

As The Witcher (1) was not released on xbox 360, the sequel has no support for importing saved data on that platform.

Answer (score 1):

The Witcher has been released for:

1. Microsoft Windows
2. OS X

Since it was not released for the Xbox 360 you can't do this.

(Hint: *different file systems* )